# Is it discussed why a baby is born without teeth?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parts-of-the-body, baby-infant

I was wondering if the idea of a baby being born without teeth, and more specifically the painful process of teething, has been discussed by the Torah or addressed by any Rabbis?

Comment: Chovos Halevavos does http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hovot/2a-2.htm

Comment: @sam Didn't read it through....but a search of the word "שן" revealed a lot of things that don't mean teeth....maybe you meant to link to a different part?

Comment: Maybe try שיניים

Answer (score 2):

Didn't see a source for this anywhere, so don't think it's authoritative.

In Kabbalistic thought, there's the concept that some things draw nourishment from higher things. With the concept of חנוך לנער על פי דרכו, if the baby is meant to draw nourishment from the mother, God made it easier for him.

Note: without the Kabbalistic part, Answers.com says the same thing- that babies have no teeth so they can nurse.